# declare and use a string variable in oracle sql developer 4.1.3.20

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So at work we've been using Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.3.20 lately to query our data so I wrote this snippet of code (its actually much longer by 8 or so more table joins):

```
select
        s.NAME as "Shipment ID"
       ,k.STATUS_ID as "Status"
       ,u.SCR_NO as "SPID"           
from xyz.DRUG_KIT k
left join xyz.DR_SHIP s on s.ID = k.SHIPMENT_ID
left join xyz.USR_PAT u on u.PAT_ID = k.PAT_ID
```

When I have to switch to another table in a different database, I have been copy pasting everywhere above where you see 'xyz' but surely there has to ba better way? I use to use SQL Server Management Studio 2014 but we had to switch to this once we began using oracle databases. How would I declare a varchar(?) variable in Oracle SQL Developer so I can just use that one variable in place of XYZ and at the top of the query I just can set that variable equal whatever necessary in one place if that makes sense. It becomes cumbersome when I copy paste something wrong on one line when I"m trying to join about 10+ tables together to retrieve data.

Comment: What are you doing with the data that's queried?  Are you just visually inspecting it, inserting it somewhere, etc?

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL to do that. But as JBC asked, what do you plan to do with the result?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get any notifications to my inbox as I expected for any replies to this (I am just now logging in for the first time since writing this question, perhaps it went to my junk mail) but all I'm doing with the data is inspecting and or viewing it. I basically join these tables at work to help speed up looking for specific data changes to the oracle tables our developers use when coding systems.

Comment: Hello I just left a lengthy reply and its all gone. Are my comments not saving / committing when I leave them? I'm still new to this community sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XYZ is the owner of the table, not a different database.  If you are connected as user XYZ, then you don't need to prefix XYZ to the table name, it's only required if you are attempting to access objects owned by a different "SCHEMA".

You can change the current "parsing" schema of your session by issuing an alter session command:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=PDQ;
```

and then select from objects the user PDQ has granted you select privs on:

```
select
    s.NAME as "Shipment ID"
   ,k.STATUS_ID as "Status"
   ,u.SCR_NO as "SPID"           
from DRUG_KIT k
left join DR_SHIP s on s.ID = k.SHIPMENT_ID
left join USR_PAT u on u.PAT_ID = k.PAT_ID;
```

You can then alter your schema back to XYZ and perform the same select statement and get different results based on the contents of the tables as owned by XYZ:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=XYZ;

select
    s.NAME as "Shipment ID"
   ,k.STATUS_ID as "Status"
   ,u.SCR_NO as "SPID"           
from DRUG_KIT k
left join DR_SHIP s on s.ID = k.SHIPMENT_ID
left join USR_PAT u on u.PAT_ID = k.PAT_ID;
```

To make the DR_SHIP table owned by PDQ accessable from the XYZ schema, a private synonym to PDQ.DR_SIP can be created in place of the table onwed by XYZ:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM DR_SHIP FOR PDQ.DR_SHIP;
```

On the other hand if you want the PDQ version of the DRUG_KIT table accessible from all SCHEMAs in the DB, you can create a public synonym:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM DRUG_KIT FOR PDQ.DRUG_KIT;
```

If none of the above meet your needs, you can use SQL*Plus style substitution variables:

```
ACCEPT user;
select
    s.NAME as "Shipment ID"
   ,k.STATUS_ID as "Status"
   ,u.SCR_NO as "SPID"           
from &user..DRUG_KIT k
left join &user..DR_SHIP s on s.ID = k.SHIPMENT_ID
left join &user..USR_PAT u on u.PAT_ID = k.PAT_ID;
```

But you need to understand that these won't necessarily work outside of SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, SQLcl, and possibly a couple of other SQL development environments.

Comment: I'm trying to follow what you're saying but at the top when you say:

" If you are connected as user XYZ, then you don't need to prefix XYZ to the table name"

Comment: That is not exactly true. I'm not a database administrator at all but hopefully I can explain this to where it makes a little more sense but I DO have to add the xyz part because if I don't, oracle sql developer doesn't know what I'm trying to access. Other than taking some sort of screen shot of what I'm trying to say, this is kind of out of my realm of understanding what our DBAs did when arranging the oracle tables

We use to connect to the schema but now we all have one schema to connect to with all the different projects underneath it and their respective tables.

Comment: I meant to say above we use to connect to each individual project schema with its respective tables in it but now we connect to a single schema with all our projects beneath that a section called "Other Users" and from there we can open each project within the "Other Users" to view tables. Does that help?

Comment: Ok, What you're describing is the common situation where your login accounts schema is different from the table owners schema.  So for example you're logging in as user ABC, but user XYZ owns some tables of the tables (and views) in your application and perhaps other users (PDQ?) own other tables.  To access the tables and views of other users you need to either prefix the table/view with the owning schema's name, or create synonyms (public or private) to objects, or alter your parsing schema as needed.  Each of those options are shown above.

Comment: Ok I tried the above example:

`ACCEPT user;
select
    s.NAME as "Shipment ID"
   ,k.STATUS_ID as "Status"
   ,u.SCR_NO as "SPID"           
from &user..DRUG_KIT k
left join &user..DR_SHIP s on s.ID = k.SHIPMENT_ID
left join &user..USR_PAT u on u.PAT_ID = k.PAT_ID;`

but I get a box that pops up stating to enter value for user so in the text box I put in the name of the user which in my example is xyz but when I click ok it asks me again (I think for every table I'm joining) but after my 3rd entry I get an error stating invalid table name. Did I leave something out?

Comment: Sorry about the poor formatting. Still trying to get use to this and I don't seem to have edit privileges for some reason.

Comment: Ok I must have did something wrong the first time. It works, but will I have to re-enter the user name 10+ times every time I execute this?

Comment: I'm not sure what PDQ is or if that applies to my situation

Comment: If you are using SQL Developer, you can execute the `ACCEPT user;` line separately from the main query, and it will remember the value for `&user.`  Otherwise you can change the first `&user.` to `&&user.` and it will prompt you once instead of multiple times, but you'll need to execute the `ACCEPT user;` statement to change users.  and PDQ that's just an example schema name like XYZ or ABC.  Since I don't know your list of schemas I just followed your 3 letter sequence XYZ with the next one that comes to my mind PDQ. eXamine Your Zipper Pretty Darn Quick ;)

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I got mixed up thinking PDQ was a piece of software that runs alongside Oracle I was unaware of lol :P
Yes we are currently using Oracle SQL Developer. Our developers run something else called Toad. :)

I made sure to execute the `ACCEPT user;` statement first and then the below query and that ran much better! Thank you so much for helping me with this. :)

Comment: Hopefully this is my last comment / question but still related. This snippet of commands works for me: 

    ACCEPT user; 
    select s.NAME as "Shipment ID" 
    ,k.STATUS_ID as "Status" 
    ,u.SCR_NO as "SPID" 
    from &&user..DRUG_KIT k 
    left join &user..DR_SHIP s on s.ID = k.SHIPMENT_ID 
    left join &user..USR_PAT u on u.PAT_ID = k.PAT_ID;

but if I run the `accept user;` command separate, the bottom code still executes retaining the original user I entered. I thought executing accept user; would switch the user but it doesn't. How do I switch?

Comment: For example I originally entered user A when prompted, but now I need to switch to user B but when I execute `accept user;` and enter user B, the sql query below accept user is still returning rows for user A instead of B. How would I switch to another user without having to open a new SQL worksheet and copy pasting everything into there to view tables under user B?

Comment: You can use the `undefine` command to clear the setting and the `define` command to expilcitly change it. so `undefine user` would remove the current value of user, while `define user=B` would change it's value to B without prompting.

Comment: You're the best. I swear I tried googling an answer first before asking on here but all I got were results talking about  `alter session` which I don't think applies to my situation. Thanks a million !

Comment: Well an `alter session` statement was one of the options I provided.

Comment: Oh I thought that was just for switching schemas which I'm not trying to do. I'm still learning. :)

Answer (score 0):

At the database level, you probably want public synonyms. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm